# Applying force to sphere sends it in unpredictable directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to move (fire) a sphere in the direction of a mouse click. But when I click, the sphere moves in unpredictable directions.

My code for adding the force to move the sphere:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){

    RaycastHit hit;

    /**
    * We r using raycasting to detect mouse click on plane
    * */
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
        newPosition = hit.point;
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce( (newPosition).normalized * 25, ForceMode.Impulse  );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've supplied an incorrect argument for `Rigidbody.AddForce()`. The vector you supply for the first argument should not be the **position** you want the force to point towards - it should be the **direction** of the force, multiplied by the magnitude.

In this case, you can calculate the direction of the force by subtracting the current position of the object from the target position:

```
Vector3 forceDir = newPosition - transform.position;
this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce( forceDir.normalized * 25, ForceMode.Impulse  );
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.